# Extraer elementos aleatorios de un array en php

Tags: php, array

Hola me gustaría alguna ayuda o explicación de como extraer mas de un resultado de un array de forma aleatoria usando php. Asta el momento e logrado este código:

```
<?php
$N = mt_rand(2,4);
$ele = array('#instagood','#love','#beautiful','#me','#follow','#cute','#photooftheday','#followme','#tagforlikes','#happy','#food','#selfie','#like','#summer','
#picoftheday','#igers','#tbt','#friends','#fun','#fashion','#instadaily','#instalike','#follow4follow','#amazing','#music','#instamood','#nofilter','#nature','#life','#girls');
$cla = array_rand($ele, $N);
foreach($cla as $clave)
{
    $emojis = str_pad($ele[$clave], 30);
    echo $emojis;
}
?>
```

Asta ese ejemplo funciona bien . pero al momento de poner el código de esta forma :

```
<?php
$N = mt_rand(2,4);
$ele = array('#instagood','#love','#beautiful','#me','#follow','#cute','#photooftheday','#followme','#tagforlikes','#happy','#food','#selfie','#like','#summer','
#picoftheday','#igers','#tbt','#friends','#fun','#fashion','#instadaily','#instalike','#follow4follow','#amazing','#music','#instamood','#nofilter','#nature','#life','#girls');
$cla = array_rand($ele, $N);
foreach($cla as $clave)
{
    $emojis = str_pad($ele[$clave], 30);

}

echo $emojis;
?>
```

No da los mismos resultados y lastimosamente lo necesito de esa manera para cumplir con el valor de otra variable . si pueden darme alguna solución o otra manera de lograr extraer  mas de un elemento aleatorio de un array se los agradezco . Saludes ..

Comment: Entonces debes poner `.=` para ir agregando en cada ciclo de lo contrario con `=` solo sobrescribes la variable, usa lo sig  `$emojis .= str_pad($ele[$clave], 30);` ademas tienes que declarar la variable `$emojis=""` antes de comensar el ciclo

Comment: Tienes razón gracias por el dato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloca un contador y convierte la variable que guarda tus datos en un array de esta forma:

```
$N = mt_rand(2,4);
$ele = array('#instagood','#love','#beautiful','#me','#follow','#cute','#photooftheday','#followme','#tagforlikes','#happy','#food','#selfie','#like','#summer','
#picoftheday','#igers','#tbt','#friends','#fun','#fashion','#instadaily','#instalike','#follow4follow','#amazing','#music','#instamood','#nofilter','#nature','#life','#girls');
$cla = array_rand($ele, $N);
$i=0;
foreach($cla as $clave)
{
    $emojis[$i] = str_pad($ele[$clave], 30);
$i++;
}

var_dump($emojis); //muestra todos los valores que necesitas
```

Comment: Gracias pero lo que busco es que la variable $emojis tenga un resultado parecido a esto "'#instagood #love  #beautiful"

Comment: Precisamente. Con el var_dump que te coloco al final, eso es lo que obtienes. No necesariamente obtendrás "#instagood #love #beautiful" ya que tu mismo mencionas que deseas que aparezcan palabras aleatorias. Probaste el código que posteé?

Comment: Si amigo pero al final la variable $emojis es un array ?

Comment: Si, debe serlo ya que vas a guardar más de un valor en ella por la forma como utilizas tu foreach.